Writing a shell script to extract the logs within the specified timestamp
Below is the script. When I try to execute it, it says there is an error parsing the date.
[17:02:04:308][01-03-2024] <-- This is the structure of the timestamp in my log file. The error in the terminal:
./extract_logs.sh serverout.txt "[17:02:04:308][01-03-2024]" "[17:02:04:325][01-03-2024]"
date: invalid date ‘ 17:02:04:308  01-03-2024 ’
date: invalid date ‘ 17:02:04:325  01-03-2024 ’
date: invalid date ‘ 17:02:04:227  01-03-2024 ’
./extract_logs.sh: line 39: [: : integer expression expected
date: invalid date ‘ 17:02:04:303  01-03-2024 ’
./extract_logs.sh: line 39: [: : integer expression expected
date: invalid date ‘ 17:02:04:304  01-03-2024 ’
./extract_logs.sh: line 39: [: : integer expression expected
date: invalid date ‘ 17:02:04:308  01-03-2024 ’
./extract_logs.sh: line 39: [: : integer expression expected

The code:
#!/bin/bash

# Function to convert timestamp to seconds since epoch
convert_to_seconds() {
    local timestamp=$1
    date -d "$timestamp" +%s
}

# Check if correct number of arguments are passed
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <log_file_name> <start_timestamp> <end_timestamp>"
    echo "Timestamps should be in the format '[HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]'"
    exit 1
fi

log_file=$1
start_timestamp=$2
end_timestamp=$3

# Convert start and end timestamps to seconds since epoch
start_seconds=$(convert_to_seconds "$start_timestamp")
end_seconds=$(convert_to_seconds "$end_timestamp")

# Check if log file exists
if [ ! -f "$log_file" ]; then
    echo "File not found: $log_file"
    exit 1
fi

# Read the log file line by line
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Extract the timestamp from the log line
    if [[ $line =~ (\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3})\]\[([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})\] ]]; then
        log_time="[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}][${BASH_REMATCH[2]}]"
        log_seconds=$(convert_to_seconds "$log_time")

        # Check if log time is within the specified range
        if [ "$log_seconds" -ge "$start_seconds" ] && [ "$log_seconds" -le "$end_seconds" ]; then
            echo "$line"
        fi
    fi
done < "$log_file"



Why is your datestamp format insane in the first place?

i don't know, i am a newbie. this was the task assigned by my mentor and shared me this log file

Your example passes in two timestamps from different thousandths of the same second, but your script logic is converting all timestamps to epoch seconds (which throws away fractions). That's not going to work.

The simple explanation is that date stamps in your crazy format are not acceptable to date.
A workaround is to convert the dates to something sane; but since these are just numbers, you don't really need to convert the value to seconds -- just do a simple string comparison after reordering the fields.
#!/bin/bash
 
# Check if correct number of arguments are passed
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <log_file_name> <start_timestamp> <end_timestamp>"
    echo "Timestamps should be in the format '[HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]'"
    exit 1
fi
 
log_file=$1
start_timestamp=$2
end_timestamp=$3
 
# Check if log file exists
if [ ! -f "$log_file" ]; then
    echo "File not found: $log_file"
    exit 1
fi
 
awk -v start="$start_timestamp" -v end="$end_timestamp" '
  function parsedate(date) {
        split(date, a, /[]:[-]+/)
        return a[8] "-" a[7] "-" a[6] "T" a[2] ":" a[3] ":" a[4] "." a[5]
  }
  BEGIN {
    st = parsedate(start)
    et = parsedate(end)
  }
  ((p = parsedate($0)) >= st) && (p <= et)' "$1"

I refactored the main logic to Awk as that is significantly more succinct than the equivalent Bash code.
Demo: https://ideone.com/GOgdoP
Tangentially, perhaps note also that there are multiple versions of date. You are apparently on Linux, which uses GNU date (which supports e.g. the -d option for specifying a date). On e.g. BSD / MacOS you have different options (including an option to specify how exactly to convert a string in some wacky format to a date, but with many other oddities).

tripleee is right - your timestamp structure is not great.
If you have any control over that, fix it.
If possible, use YEAR-MO-DY HH::MM::SS, as in
$: date +'%F %T'
2024-06-11 08:02:06

That said, it's still all just a matter of correctly parsing your data.
$: [[ $timestamp =~ ^\[([[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}):[[:digit:]]{3}\]\[([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{4})\] ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}" || echo nomatch
[17:02:04:308][01-03-2024]
17:02:04
01
03
2024

$: date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" +%s                                                     1709334124

So to rewrite your existing function:
$: convert_to_seconds() {
  if [[ $1 =~ ^\[([[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}):[[:digit:]]{3}\]\[([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{4})\]$ ]]
  then date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" +%s
  else echo "Invalid timestamp: '$1'" >&2
       return 1
  fi
}

$: convert_to_seconds $timestamp
1709334124

$: convert_to_seconds foo
Invalid timestamp: 'foo'

Prettied up just a little -
convert_to_seconds() {
  local timestamp="$1" format
  local pattern=$'^\[([[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}):[[:digit:]]{3}\]' # the time portion
        pattern+=$'\[([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{4})\]$'           # the date portion
   if [[ $1 =~ $pattern ]]
   then format="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # parsed
        date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" +%s;
   else echo "Invalid timestamp: '$1'" >&2
   return 1
   fi
}


tripleee's also right that awk is going to be a lot more efficient for this.

sadly, i have no authority to change the timestamp format.
