Extract the logs that are logged within 2 timestamps
I am in a situation where I wrote a script to extract the lines within the specified time frame from a log file. This script works fine until I found that it is only printing the lines which has the timestamp that is logged within the specified time and leaves the lines which are not having a timestamp but logged within the specified time frame. Those lines which are not having a timestamp but present within the specified time frame must also be printed. But I don't know how to achieve this.
The below is the log file
[17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]some log info here:
step1
step2
step3
[17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]some log here
a
b
c
[17:02:12:185][01-03-2024]Time taken   : 11


start timestamp: [17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]
end timestamp: [17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]
But I also want those a, b, c lines since they are also logged during the end timestamp
Please note that I have no authority to change this timestamp format. I know this is not in  a correct format.
Below is the script
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check the timestamp format
timestamp_pattern_checker() {
    local input_pattern="^\[([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3})\]\[([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})\]$"
    if [[ ! $1 =~ $input_pattern ]]; then
        echo "Invalid Timestamp pattern"
        echo "Timestamps should be in the format '[HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]' or HH"
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Function to convert hours to timestamp format
convert_hours_to_timestamp() {
    local hour=$1
    printf "[%02d:00:00:000]" "$hour"
}

# Check if correct number of arguments are passed
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <log_file_name> <start_timestamp> <end_timestamp>"
    echo "Timestamps should be in the format '[HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]' or as integers representing hours (00 to 23)"
    exit 1
fi

log_file=$1
start_input=$2
end_input=$3

# Check if log file exists
if [ ! -f "$log_file" ]; then
    echo "File not found: $log_file"
    exit 1
fi

# Determine if inputs are hours or full timestamps
if [[ $start_input =~ ^[0-9]{2}$ && $end_input =~ ^[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
    if [[ $start_input -ge 0 && start_input -le 23 && $end_input -ge 0 && $end_input -le 23 ]]; then
        if [[ $start_input -le $end_input ]]; then
            start_timestamp=$(convert_hours_to_timestamp "$start_input")
            end_timestamp=$(convert_hours_to_timestamp "$end_input")

            # Extract unique dates from log file
            unique_dates=$(awk -F'[][]' '{print $4}' "$log_file" | sort | uniq)

            start_timestamps=()
            end_timestamps=()
            for date in $unique_dates; do
                start_timestamps+=("${start_timestamp}[$date]")
                end_timestamps+=("${end_timestamp}[$date]")
            done
        else
           echo "Error: start hour must be less than or equal to end hour."
           exit 1
        fi
    else
       echo "Error: Hours must be between 00 and 23."
       exit 1
    fi
else
    start_timestamp=$start_input
    end_timestamp=$end_input
    timestamp_pattern_checker "$start_timestamp"
    timestamp_pattern_checker "$end_timestamp"
    start_timestamps=("$start_timestamp")
    end_timestamps=("$end_timestamp")
fi

awk -v starts="${start_timestamps[*]}" -v ends="${end_timestamps[*]}" '
  function parsedate(date) {
        split(date, a, /[]:[-]+/)
        return a[6] "-" a[7] "-" a[8] "T" a[1] ":" a[2] ":" a[3] ":" a[4] "." a[5]
  }
  BEGIN {
    split(starts, start_arr, " ")
    split(ends, end_arr, " ")
    for (i in start_arr) {
        st[i] = parsedate(start_arr[i])
        et[i] = parsedate(end_arr[i])
    }
    log_count = 0
  }
  {
    p = parsedate($0)
    for (i in st) {
        if (p >= st[i] && p <= et[i]) {
            print $0
            log_count = 1
        }
    }
  }
  END {
    if (log_count == 0) {
        print "Nothing was logged at this given time frame"
    }
  }' "$log_file"


For context, earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78607470/writing-a-shell-script-to-extract-the-logs-within-the-specified-timestamp

are the inputs (start_timestamp and end_timestamp) guaranteed to have an exact match within the file? in other words, given the sample input, could start_timestamp be a string that does not exist in the sample input, eg, start_timestamp='[17:00:00:00][01-03-2024] '?

what happens if you find a match for start_timestamp but not end_timestamp? do you start printing when you see start_timestamp and then print the rest of the file? or in this scenario would you print nothing since you never find a match for end_timestamp?

Finally, I figured it out with the help of the guys here who tried. I learned a lot. Thank you so much for reaching out to help me. The perfect answer that works for me is here.
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check the timestamp format
timestamp_pattern_checker() {
    local input_pattern="^\[([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3})\]\[([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})\]$"
    if [[ ! $1 =~ $input_pattern ]]; then
        echo "Invalid Timestamp pattern"
        echo "Timestamps should be in the format '[HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]' or HH"
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Function to convert hours to timestamp format
# Input: hour (integer)
convert_hours_to_timestamp() {
    local hour=$1
    printf "[%02d:00:00:000]" "$hour"
}

# Function to convert date to timestamp format [DD-MM-YYYY]
# Input: date (string)
convert_date_to_timestamp() {
    local date=$1
    printf "[%s]" "$date"
}

# Main script starts here
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <log_file>"
    exit 1
fi

log_file=$1

# Check if log file exists
if [ ! -f "$log_file" ]; then
    echo "File not found: $log_file"
    exit 1
fi

read -p "Enter start timestamp (HH or [HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]): " start_input
read -p "Enter end timestamp (HH or [HH:MM:SS:SSS][DD-MM-YYYY]): " end_input

# Determine if inputs are hours or full timestamps
if [[ $start_input =~ ^[0-9]{2}$ && $end_input =~ ^[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
    if [[ $start_input -ge 0 && $start_input -le 23 && $end_input -ge 0 && $end_input -le 23 ]]; then
        if [[ $start_input -le $end_input ]]; then
            start_timestamp=$(convert_hours_to_timestamp "$start_input")
            end_timestamp=$(convert_hours_to_timestamp "$end_input")

            # Extract unique dates from log file
            unique_dates=$(awk -F'[][]' '/\[/{print $4}' "$log_file" | sort | uniq)

            start_timestamps=()
            end_timestamps=()
            for date in $unique_dates; do
                start_timestamps+=("${start_timestamp}[$date]")
                end_timestamps+=("${end_timestamp}[$date]")
            done
        else
            echo "Error: start hour must be less than or equal to end hour."
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "Error: Hours must be between 00 and 23."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    timestamp_pattern_checker "$start_input"
    timestamp_pattern_checker "$end_input"
    start_timestamps=("$start_input")
    end_timestamps=("$end_input")
fi

awk -v starts="${start_timestamps[*]}" -v ends="${end_timestamps[*]}" '
  function parsedate(date) {
        split(date, a, /[]:[-]+/)
        #ISO 8601 format timestamp conversion
        return a[8] "-" a[7] "-" a[6] "T" a[2] ":" a[3] ":" a[4] "." a[5]
  }
  BEGIN {
    split(starts, start_arr, " ")
    split(ends, end_arr, " ")
    for (i in start_arr) {
        st[i] = parsedate(start_arr[i])
        et[i] = parsedate(end_arr[i])
    }
    log_count = 0
  }
  {
    if (match($0, /^\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\]\[[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\]/)) {
        p = parsedate(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH))
        in_range = 0
        for (i in st) {
            if (p >= st[i] && p <= et[i]) {
                in_range = 1
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if (in_range) {
        print
        log_count = 1
    }
  }
  END {
    if (log_count == 0) {
        print "Nothing was logged at this given time frame"
    }
  }
' "$log_file"


Don't try to use sed for this or it'll fail when the specific timestamp you want to use in a range doesn't exist in your input. Here's a start at least with any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v beg='[17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]' -v end='[17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]' '
    BEGIN {
        beg = ts2iso(beg)
        end = ts2iso(end)
    }

    match($0,/^\[([0-9]{2}:){3}[0-9]{3}]\[([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{4}]/) {
        cur = ts2iso(substr($0,1,RLENGTH))
    }

    (beg <= cur) && (cur <= end)

    function ts2iso(old     ,t) {
        # Convert unsortable timestamp to ISO 8601 format
        split(old,t,/[][-]+/)
        return t[5] "-" t[4] "-" t[3] "T" t[2]
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
[17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]some log info here:
step1
step2
step3
[17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]some log here
a
b
c


As ever, this is more elegant and succinct than mine, but fails to support the OP's use of Bash arrays to specify multiple time ranges. (Granted, the question fails to mention anything about this requirement.)

@triplee thanks. Yeah, I'm not considering the rest of the OPs code, just the bit they asked about ("Extract the logs that are logged within 2 timestamps") as their whole bash script should just be a single awk script rather then setting up bash arrays and then calling awk and I suspect a lot of what they're doing is just due to their current implementation and doesn't actually need to be done to get the functionality they want but they didn't provide requirements nor enough sample input/output to test all of that with anyway so that'd be a whole other question if the OP cares to pursue it.

You can modify your script to keep on printing as long as you don't see another timestamp.
awk -v starts="${start_timestamps[*]}" -v ends="${end_timestamps[*]}" '
  function parsedate(date) {
        split(date, a, /[]:[-]+/)
        return a[8] "-" a[7] "-" a[6] "T" a[1] ":" a[2] ":" a[3] ":" a[4] "." a[5]
  }
  BEGIN {
    split(starts, start_arr, " ")
    split(ends, end_arr, " ")
    for (i in start_arr) {
        st[i] = parsedate(start_arr[i])
        et[i] = parsedate(end_arr[i])
    }
    log_count = 0
  }
  /^\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\]\[[0-3][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-9]{4}\]/{
    p = parsedate($0)
    printing = 0
    for (i in st) {
        if (p >= st[i] && p <= et[i]) {
            printing = 1
            log_count = 1
            break
        }
    }
  }
  printing
  END {
    if (log_count == 0) {
        print "Nothing was logged at this given time frame"
    }
  }' "$log_file"

This adds a condition to only parse dates on lines which start with a date stamp, and replaces print with printing = 1; and then the printing condition will simply print the current line if printing is not 0. This way, printing will be re-evaluated each time you see a time stamp, but otherwise, the result from the most recent line which did have a time stamp will be applied.
I also had to flip the order of a[8] and a[6] in parsedate -- I guess those were left from a buggy earlier version of my answer to your previous question.
Here's a demo with some debug prints to help you see what it's doing, and hopefully help you figure out how to troubleshoot code yourself: https://ideone.com/MpA28H

It hurts to type dates in this wicked format. Perhaps a good exercise would be to create a copy of the file with datestamps fixed into machine-readable format for your further experimentation.

Try sed:
sed -n "/pattern1/,/pattern2/p" file_name

This sed will give you all strings between pattern1 and pattern2 including pattern strings.

While this is technically not untrue, it really fails to solve the OP's problem in any meaningful way. You'd have to know exactly which timestamps exist in the file, or craft a quite nontrivial regular expression to identify the interesting lines. And even then, what if the last line of a range you want to print has contents which are identical to other lines which should not be printed? It can be done, of course; but basically, not like this.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task in the following way, let file.txt content be
[17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]some log info here:
step1
step2
step3
[17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]some log here
a
b
c
[17:02:12:185][01-03-2024]Time taken   : 11

then
awk -v start="[17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]" -v end="[17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]" '
    function parsestamp(stamp){
        patsplit(stamp,a,"[0-9]+");
        return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%d", a[7], a[6], a[5], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4])+0
    }
    BEGIN{
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
        startime=parsestamp(start);
        endtime=parsestamp(end)
    }
    /^\[[0-9:]+\]/{
        inx+=1
    }
    {
        arr[inx]=arr[inx]"\n" $0
    }
    END{
        for(i in arr){
            stamp=parsestamp(arr[i]);
            if(startime<=stamp&&stamp<=endtime){
                print substr(arr[i],2)
}}}' file.txt

gives output
[17:02:12:161][01-03-2024]some log info here:
step1
step2
step3
[17:02:12:163][01-03-2024]some log here
a
b
c

Explanation: I define function parsestamp which turns timestamps of your format into integers, which might be compared (later timestamp gives bigger number). Observe said function is crafted so to also work if there is non-date-time related information after timestamp. In BEGIN I inform GNU AWK to traverse array by index numerically ascending and compute number values for start and end. If line starts with [ one-or-more (digit or :) ] then I assume it is timestamp and increase inx by 1. I append newline and current line to value of array arr under key inx. After all lines are processed I iterate over array arr and for each value compute number based at timestamp contained therein. If it is inside range start-end (inclusive) I print line without 1st character, which is newline (which is here due to how lines are collected).
(Tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Reading the entire file into memory so you can loop over it all again in END is inefficient and will potentially break or run extremely slowly on large files. The other solutions here process each line there and then, and can then forget about it.
